# SQL Update values based on VLOOKUP results

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

I am using DataGrip and have an Oracle SQL database with 2 tables.

I am trying to update the values of *column01* in *Table01* (currently all values are *NULL*) with vlookup/outer join from another table. Both Table01 and Table02 have one common column. The idea should be something like :

```
UPDATE Table01 SET RescorceName = (
  SELECT AntennaSection 
  FROM Table02 
  WHERE Table01.CellName = Table02.Cellname
)
```

I've added an example below of what I want the result to look like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smPlD.png)

Any advice would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make sure you only update some of the records

```
UPDATE Table01 
SET RescorceName = (
  SELECT AntennaSection 
  FROM Table02 
  WHERE Table01.CellName = Table02.Cellname
    -- note, this is a horrible way to solve the problem -- we should instead
    -- know why we are getting more than one row and change the query.
    AND ROWNUM = 1
)
WHERE Table01.CellName IN (
 SELECT Table02.Cellname
 FROM Table02
)
```

Comment: Hi there! If I apply the above syntax I receive the following error : ORA-01427:single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: that means that `SELECT AntennaSection FROM Table02 WHERE Table01.CellName = Table02.Cellname` returns more than one row for a single value of Cellname -- *Clearly* it is not possible to assign two things to RescorceName.  Which one do you want to assign -- what is the business rule here?

Comment: I double-checked and there were duplicated values in Table01.CellName.

Comment: @RemusRaphael -- so you want the first column in the result?

Comment: @RemusRaphael -- you can use ROWNUM in oracle -- but it is horrible.

Comment: I updated the values from Table01 in column CellName to include only distinct values but I still receive the same error. At the end of the day, I want to update the values in Table01, column ResourceName with the corresponding values from Table02, column AntennaSection - based on matching values between CellName in Table01 and Table02. Table01 is the one that should have the correct data

Comment: @RemusRaphael -- as I said before -- it is table 2 that is returning two results.  table 2 needs to have distinct values.  table1 can have multiple and it would not be a problem it would just update them the same way.